# No Connection Adapters Using ThreadPool

Tags: python, url

I'm running ThreadPool through a list of urls currently in a csv. When the code runs it kicks back the error posted below:

```
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['http://axiomglobal.sharepoint.com/sites/MarkandElena-Strategic']'
```

It looks like python is looking at the brackets as part of the url, but the list itself appears to omit them:

```
[['http://axiomglobal.sharepoint.com/sites/123456'], ['http://axiomglobal.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointo365globaltestsite'], ['http:3456789']
```

Is there something in the code below that is causing it to search for the sites in the list with the brackets included?

I've tried using a single url against the ThreadLoop portion of the code, rather than the entire list and it generates the correct result.

```
def get_site_status(site):
    try:
        response = requests.get(site)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print('Connection Refused')
        return 1
    if response.status_code == 401:
        print('web site exists, permission needed')
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        print('web site does not exist')
    elif response.status_code == 400:
        print('web site does not exist')
    elif response.status_code == 403:
        print('web site forbidden')
    elif response.status_code == 423:
        print('web site locked')
    elif response.status_code == 200:
        print('web site exists and is available')
    else:
        print('other')
    return 0
pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
​
results = pool.map_async(get_site_status, Row_list)
​
print('Results: {}'.format(results.get()))
```

I expect the code to populate a  list of each row with it's result from the ThreadPool part of the code (approx. 1500 rows of urls).

Answer (score 0):

`gevent` is way faster with requests. You are not trapping the errors correctly or handing it an SSL cert incase of an upgrade.

```
from gevent import monkey, spawn, joinall
monkey.patch_all()
import requests, certifi
from time import time
t0 = time()
Row_list = ['http://axiomglobal.sharepoint.com/sites/123456', 'http://axiomglobal.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointo365globaltestsite', 'http:3456789', 'https://www.yahoo.com']
def get_site_status(site):
    try:
        response = requests.get(site, verify=certifi.where())
        status = response.status_code
    except:
        print('Connection Refused')
        return False
    if status == 401:
        print('web site exists, permission needed')
    elif status == 404:
        print('web site does not exist')
    elif status == 400:
        print('web site does not exist')
    elif status == 403:
        print('web site forbidden')
    elif status == 423:
        print('web site locked')
    elif status == 200:
        print('web site exists and is available')
    else:
        print('other')
    return True
threads = []
for row in Row_list:
    threads.append(spawn(get_site_status, row))
joinall(threads)

for thread in threads:
    print thread.value

print time() - t0
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized the issue, I was using a list within a list earlier on in the code which caused the loop to look for '[url]' rather than 'url'